# Unreadable old DVD Disc

Tags: data-recovery, dvd

I have an old DVD which contains the recording of a concert we made with the band I had when I was in high school, this is I think the only recording we have.

It was readable 1 year ago, but now none of the device I tried can read it. It just doesn't recognize that there's a disc in the reader...

I tried many data recovery software (CD Recovery Toolbox, MiniTool Power Data Recovery ...), but since the reader says it has no disc in it, it doesn't do anything.

The DVD is slightly scratched but seems to be still in a good shape.

Any ideas about what I can do to try to make it readable ?
Perhaps a software that can directly address the DVD player driver to try to recover the readable parts of it?

Here is the picture of the DVD, it looks to have a lot more scratches than I actually see with a naked eye, surely because my smartphone used the flash when I took the picture.

[image]

Comment: Take a look: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-repair-and-recover-data-from-damaged-cds-or-dvds/

Comment: I doubt it is damaged, it probably is really old media that newer dvd drives don't have the firmware to support it, try to find an old PC that still works to read it, that or look for an old dvd optical drive at a garage sale. Try it on every pc you come in contact with (older the better), you might get lucky.

Comment: @duDE Yep I'v seen that, perhaps I'll try, but there are not much scratches actually, that's why I thought there might be some other reason

Comment: If drive won't even attempt to read the disk, not a great deal you can do, sounds like the scratches are the cause of your problems.

Comment: Is this a factory-pressed DVD, or a DVD that was burned? (DVD RW? DVD R?)

Comment: Scratches don't seem that bad (they're barely visible except for 3 little ones), and no this is not a factory-pressed DVD, it was burned....

Comment: can you upload a picture of your dvd?.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia added the picture, but the flash shows a lot more scratches than I can see without it

Comment: @ppetrov this dvd is very very schrached and there is not a way to fix it, that picture explain all, just drop it to the trash and keep forward.

Comment: You can try something like [Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier](ww.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29) it **MIGHT** get you the file.  The problem is the data if anything is recovered will not be complete.  If the disk won't even show up in explorer then this program won't help at all.

Comment: @Ramhound I heard about this, but the disk won't show in the explorer.... I think I'll try the thing in Enis's answer, you never know ;) Anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: Wiping baby oil on the surface can sometimes make scratched disc readable again.

Answer (score 3):

The scratches on the disc appear to be axial/spiral, as though whatever was playing the disc was jolted or tilted at some point. These kind of scratches can cause a lot of problems because too many neighbouring bits can be affected for the error correction to be able to work.

It may be worth asking any shops that sell second hand CD's/DVD's whether they can try to fix it for you. Some of them have a machine that can polish the surface of a moderately scratched disc to make it work again. It's not the sort of thing you would want to do many times to a disc as it actually removes a thin layer of the plastic coating. The scratches on your disc look quite light but for deeper scratches it won't work as well.

In the UK it would be stores like Game and CEX that do this, in France I think the equivalent might be Micromania. They would normally charge a small fee. I've used this service myself with reasonable results, although that was a factory pressed DVD and not a writable one.

Answer (score 1):

Discs are not that resistant to damage, and it turns out some crappy discs can go bad after just a couple of years, if you don't handle them with care.

To quote a research:

> The causes of disc rot are manifold and can include one of the
>   following:
>    - oxidation or corrosion of reflective layer;
>    - physical damage to disc surfaces or edges;
>    - galvanic reaction between layers and coatings;
>    - chemical reactions with contaminants;
>    - ultra-violet light damage;
>    - breaking down of disc materials, e.g. de-bonding of adhesives between layers;

You can give [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FH9UOK) (or something similar) a try if you feel like disc surface is the source of the problem, but it's probably not going to help much.

Also someone mentioned using an old PC may help, but I don't see the point in it, if your drive is labeled "DVD" it's compatible. For example I have a Windows 95 CD, and my 2 year old Lenovo E530 reads it just fine. It makes more sense to use new drive as laser in it will be much more sensitive than in an old one.